# Style with css in php

Tags: php, css, while-loop

I'm new to this so please be gentle

I want to style for example $product_name, $author, $details.
I guess I could style the echos but in this case the only echo is

```
<?php 
// Connect to the MySQL database  
include "storescripts/connect_mysql.php"; 
// This block grabs the whole list for viewing
$dynamicList = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id DESC");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
             $id = $row["id"];
             $product_name = $row["product_name"];
             $author = $row["author"];
             $details = $row["details"];
             $link = $row["link"];
             $isbn = $row["isbn"];
             $isbn13 = $row["isbn13"];
             $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
             $dynamicList .= '<table width="580" border="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="120"><img src="/inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" width="120" height="184" border="0" /></td>
        <td width="456"><p>' . $product_name . '<p><br />
          <p>' . $author . '</span><br />
          <p>' . $details . '<br />
        <a href="product.php?' . $id . '">visa </a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>';
    }
} else {
    $dynamicList = "Database empty.";
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Do you want to say that you want to style the output?

Comment: this is sort of unrelated to your question, but you really should not be using the mysql_* functions as they are deprecated. Look up how to use mysqli_* or PDO.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding some CSS classes to your table cells?

```
$dynamicList .= '
<table width="580" border="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="120"><img src="/inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" width="120" height="184" border="0" /></td>
    <td width="456"><p class="product_name">' . $product_name . '<p><br />
      <p class="author">' . $author . '</span><br />
      <p class="detail">' . $details . '<br />
    <a href="product.php?' . $id . '">visa </a></td>
  </tr>
</table>';
```

In the head add some styles:

```
<style>
  .product_name{color:red;}
  .author{color:green;}
  .detail{color:blue;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add CSS rules to your stylesheet?

```
table tr td p {
// some styles
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class with styles to the `<p>` elements that contain each value

```
<td width="456"><p class="product-name">' . $product_name . '</p>...
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is only a preprocssor and coughs up the code as the page loads and before any of the css of HTML kicks in so you can style it as normal

Answer (score 0):

You can use style="" and class="" parameters on your `<p>` paragraph tags as well on the table cells `<td>`. You can also try to add for example styled `<span>` or `<div>` tags to your variables I suppose.

For example:

```
$product_name = "<span class='yourstyleclass'>$row['product_name']</span>";
```